# Using flask_profiler module to get metrics of my flask api endpoint

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I am using flask based API integrated with Swagger UI, it is working with any issues.

Now I want to know how many hits I am getting on my endpoint so after going through many documents i noticed "https://github.com/muatik/flask-profiler" is good for metrics.

So i have used a piece of code from the above git repo and after running my falsk locally.

my swagger endpoint is suddenly stopping throwing errors as below and my swagger endpoint gets stuck and the flask-profile endpoint is also not working correctly.

```
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/flask_profiler/storage/sqlite.py", line 158, in getTimeseries
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Recursive use of cursors not allowed.

zsh: segmentation fault  python3 flask.py
```

here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response, Response
import flask_profiler
import t2e
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint

hunter = Flask(__name__)
health_status = True
hunter.config["DEBUG"] = True
# swagger Code

# flask-profiler as follows:

hunter.config["flask_profiler"] = {
        "enabled": hunter.config["DEBUG"],
        "storage": {
            "engine": "sqlite"
        },
        "basicAuth":{
            "enabled": True,
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        },
        "ignore": [
            "^/static/.*"
        ]
    }

SWAGGER_URL = '/hunter'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'

SWAGGER_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(SWAGGER_URL,
                                            API_URL,
                                            config={'app_name': "Hunter_service"})

hunter.register_blueprint(SWAGGER_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)

def get_args(args):
    """
     :param fname :  args name
     "return : source, destination,port, protocol
    """
    return args.get('source').strip().lower(), args.get('destination').strip().lower(), args.get(
        'port').strip(), args.get('protocol').strip().lower()


flask_profiler.init_app(hunter)


@hunter.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@flask_profiler.profile()
def hunter_flow():
    source, destination, port, protocol = get_args(args)
    logger.info("Hunter is fetching t2e output from link")
    
    output = t2e(source, destination, port, protocol) #calling another function to check the flow
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   hunter.run()
```